# Android Studio unexpected top-level exception in libGDX project

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I have a fresh libGDX project, with gives above error message when try to build it.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\SDK_2015\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Ákos\Downloads\physics\android\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Ákos\Downloads\physics\android\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\Ă?kos\Downloads\physics\android\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
```

It is strange, I have never seen similar to this. What can causes this? I am using the most recent 1.2 version of Android Studio.

Comment: try cleaning the project then rebuilding it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can suggest you to try several things:

1. On the path `C:\Users\Ákos\Downloads...` is this symbol `Á`, possibly not recognized by `IDE`. Also on second `path` as well. Try to avoid any of non-[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters.
2. On the path `C:\Users\Ă?kos\Downloads\physics\android\build\intermediates\classes\` remove folder `classes`. Then `clean` and `rebuild` project.

But in my opinion and experience and as other answers said this is because of symbols.

Comment: Your 2nd opinion have solved this build error. Thanks!